# Set EOF with WINAPI?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, filesystems

I'm working on a project with WINAPI, where I open and edit files, and sometimes a remove data, so I'm wondering if I can set the end-of-file, so when I close the handle it doesn't save the data past the EOF. Is this possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, found the function [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531.aspx), thanks, sorry, Brad.

Comment: Good job, doing the research and answering your own question. Feel free to accept this answer as the correct one.

Comment: I do try, but sometimes I'm trying to meet a deadline like right now, and I just have to ask, since you guys are so fast :P

Comment: Understandable. Just letting you know that [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!